# codeigniter 2.0 Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in

Tags: class, codeigniter, download, controller, version

i have download the new codeigniter 2.0 and put my controller,model and view files in the new codeigniter 2.0 installation. but i got this error

Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/application/controllers/forside.php on line 3

What im doing wrong? it works with the old codeigniter version but the new one.. No :S

Hope some one can help me out

Comment: The accepted answer says to change `extends Controller` to `extends CI_Controller` in versions >=2.0. But that actually breaks my site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Class Controller not found in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492544/error-class-controller-not-found-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In CodeIgniter 2 your controllers inherit from super class `CI_Controller`, rather than the super class `Controller` used in CodeIgniter 1.

The same applies to models in CI2 which extend the class `CI_Model` rather then `Model`.

Comment: put its not cool i have do edit all my files :(, cant get my project to work right now, got a lot of errors.. and encryption_key Wtf :p

Comment: yup..it worked. also the constuctor class in should be function __construct() { // Call the constructor parent::__construct(); } http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/159834/#769301

Comment: It's pretty lame that most first-time CI people are probably encountering this error because it's in the CI intro/tutorial video http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/intro/

Answer (score 14):

I think you are not extending the controller like below;

```
<?php
class MyOwnController extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
?>
```

It's written on http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html, you have to extend **CI_Controller**

Comment: Sad but true :( Take a look at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_200.html

Comment: and my url dont work know http://localhost:8888/site/nyheder just saying "The requested URL /site/nyheder was not found on this server."

Comment: Is it working when you add "index.php"? I'm not sure about your directory structure, so test with those links too; http://localhost:8888/index.php/site/nyheader or http://localhost:8888/site/index.php/nyheader

Comment: I was having the same problem but now it just switched to `Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in /home2/mysharedservername/public_html/myappname/system/application/controllers/investor_browse.php on line 7` instead of `Class 'Controller' not found` in same. Using Bluehost.

Comment: @Sjmon you can use Notepad++ to rename all at once, open all controller on Notepad++, and when on Find & Replace dialog, klik Replace on all opened document

Answer (score 4):

Along with that CI_ prefix to your controller, any core classes you extend, you should place withing the **applications/core/** folder. This is because the core CodeIgniter classes have been moved to the **system/core/** folder.

Comment: Does this include extending the `Controller` base class? In the first two video tutorials they say to extend that with `Class Blog` in their example, and don't modify ~/applications/core.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Student extends CI_Controller {

  function Student()   {
    parent::__construct(); 

    // load helpers
    $this->load->helper('url');
  }
}
```

Including the `parent::__construct();` rather than `parent::Controller();`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Controller's name matches the prefix defined in the config:

By default, the config has:

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

If your controller is `core/SomeController.php` it won't be found because it doesn't start with `MY_`