# Error Class Controller not found in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, controller

Hello, I am getting `Controller` not found error in CodeIgniter. This is my Controller code

```
<?php

class HelloWorld extends Controller
{

    function HelloWorld()
    {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index_view');
    }

    function hello()
    {
        $this->load->view('hello_view');
    }

}
?>
```

This is the view code:

`Hello, Nice to see you!`

I have this error when it executes:

`Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in D:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_2.0.2\application\controllers\helloworld.php on line 2`

Can anyone tell me why I get this error?

Answer (score 5):

As of CodeIgniter 2.x `CI_` prefix is added to all core classes. Check the [Change Log](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/changelog.html).

`Added CI_ Prefix to all core classes.`

For CodeIgniter 2.x

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class HelloWorld extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index_view');
    }

    function hello()
    {
        $this->load->view('hello_view');
    }

}
```

For CodeIgniter 1.x

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class HelloWorld extends Controller
{

    function HelloWorld()
    {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index_view');
    }

    function hello()
    {
        $this->load->view('hello_view');
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks!!

Comment: really thanx... i was very confused

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your controller extends the parent controller class and also check your file name .

```
<?
     class Helloworld extends CI_Controller {

            function index()
            {
                   $this->load->view('index_view');    
            }

                function hello(){
                $this->load->view('hello_view'); 
                }

        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem as you, and i solved it as simple as possible just by replacing the word Controller in the line of extending parent class by CI_Controller and it's work probably and here is the solution in your code

```
<?php

class HelloWorld extends CI_Controller{

   function HelloWorld() {
    parent::Controller();
   }

  function index() {
    $this->load->view('index_view');
  }

  function hello() {
    $this->load->view('hello_view');
  }

}
?>
```

and your code will execute