# codeigniter 2.0.3-Fatal error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and i tried a lesson from one of the tutorials but it throws the following error:

```
Class 'Controller' not found in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\controllers\email.php 
on line 3
```

My code:

```
<?php

class Email extends Controller{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'username' => 'saveniroj@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password' 
        );

        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->from('saveniroj@gmail.com', 'Niroj Shakya');
        $this->email->to('saveniroj@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('This is a test email');
        $this->email->message('Oops This is Great.');

        if($this->email->send())
        {
            echo 'Your email was sent, FOOL';       
        }

        else
        {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
    }
}   

?>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Class Controller not found in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492544/error-class-controller-not-found-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the class definition to

```
class Email extends CI_Controller {
```

and in the `__construct` function

```
parent::CI_Controller();
```

In CodeIgniter 2, the default controller is CI_Controller and the default model is CI_Model, whereas in CodeIgniter 1 they were just Controller and Model.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Controller::Controller() in C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\controllers\email.php on line 6

Comment: Ah, yes. Change that line to `parent::CI_Controller();` - it needs to match the name of the class you're extending :)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you **don't need** to define a constructor for your controllers, unless you're going to add some custom functionality. Whereas in Models you need to, instead.

Answer (score 6):

Actually `parent::CI_Controller();` needs to be `parent::__construct();`. PHP will fatal error unless you are on PHP 5.1.x which I believe will alias to PHP 4 style if its missing.