# Creating and sending parameters Between Controller and View

Tags: codeigniter, php

I'm a complete beginner in CodeIgniter. I'm trying to understand the MVC pattern,which is getting a bit trickier as I'm going ahead with CodeIgniter.
This is what my Controller looks like i.e hello.php :

```
<?php
    class hello extends CI_Controller
    {
        var $name;
        var $color; 
        function hello()
        {
            parent::Controller();
            $this->name  ='Leroy';
            $this->color ='red';
        }

        function show()
        {   
            $data['name'] =$this->name;
            $data['color']=$this->color;    
            $this->load->view('show_message',$data);
        }
    }
?>
```

the view i.e show_message.php

```
<p align="center">Hello <font color="<?=$color?>"><?=$name?></font>..!!!!.</p>
```

when I run this script it gives this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Controller::Controller() in C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\controllers\hello.php on line 8
```

P.S I'm using CodeIgniter version 2.0 so I changed the class name to CI_Controller

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html see the Class Constructors section of the guide, constructor portion of your code is for old php. for new php you have to use __construct method

Comment: see my answer, I modified the constructor code for you

Comment: @FaizanAli I am able to solve the error but I still can't retrieve my name in the view....it shows `hello` as the output instead of this `hello myname`

Comment: possible duplicate of [codeigniter 2.0.3-Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\controllers\email.php on line 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358104/codeigniter-2-0-3-fatal-error-class-controller-not-found-in-c-xampp-htdocs-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function hello()
    {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->name  ='Leroy';
        $this->color ='red';
    }
```

Replace your constructor code with this

```
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->name  ='Leroy';
        $this->color ='red';
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't matter it I give any function name....I think `function __construct()` is not mandatory.

Comment: yea it is not mandatory. But sort of standard in Php

Answer (score 1):

```
  function hello()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
```

Comment: that did solve the problem.but can you explain why you used that.??.Now I'm not getting my desired output it should display `Hello myName` its just showing `hello`

Comment: 1. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php 2. Try using <?php echo $name?>

Comment: yea. short tagging might be the problem. It is turned off by default on wamp versions

Comment: @FaizanAli thankyou ...that solved my problem I just edited `php.ini file`and changed `short_open_tag Off` to `short_open_tag On`