# Codeigniter /application/core/Frontend_Controller.php not found on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have developed my website at XAMPP on Win 7 machine, and it works perfect on localhost. When I uploaded it to a live server (linux). It started showing me this error:

`Fatal error: Class 'Frontend_Controller' not found in /home/acephm3/public_html/phenomesoft.com/application/controllers/Home.php on line 3`

I've checked and applied everything I could from google but no luck at all.

I am using CI version 3.0.3.

I have set `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';`

Created `My_Controller.php` as follows in `/application/core`:

```
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code

    }

    public function send_mail($from, $from_name, $to, $subject, $message, $smtp, $debug) { 

        $this->load->library('email');

        if (!$smtp) {

            $this->email->from($from, $from_name);
            $this->email->to($to);

            $this->email->subject($subject);
            $this->email->message($message);

            if ( $this->email->send() ) {

                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'We\'ve received your message. Thank you for contacting us.');
                redirect('contact_us');

            } else {

                if ($debug) {
                    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
                }

                return false;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Included:

```
include_once('Frontend_Controller.php');
```

Created `Frontend_Controller.php` in `/application/core/` as follows:

```
class Frontend_Controller extends My_Controller {

    public $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code

        $this->data = array();
    }

    public function _load_template($tpl, $data)
    {
        $this->load->view('frontend/includes/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('frontend/'.$tpl, $data);
        $this->load->view('frontend/includes/footer', $data);
    }

}
```

Created a controller `Home.php` under `apllication/controllers/`:

```
class Home extends Frontend_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->_load_template('home', $this->data);
    }

}
```

Set `$route['default_controller'] = 'home';` in routes.php.

What else I have to do? Please note it once again that I have no issues on localhost.

Comment: Hope this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845806/codeigniter-2-0-fatal-error-class-controller-not-found-in

Comment: No this isn't my case.. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rather used another approach, took me a whole day to figure this out.

1. Removed `My_Controller.php` and `Frontend_Controller.php` from `application/core` folder.
2. Created a new controller `Application.php` in `application/controllers` and extended it from `CI_Controller`.
3. Created another controller `Frontend.php` in `application/controllers` and extended it from `Application` controller (Don't forget to include `Application.php` at top of this `Frontend.php` controller).
4. Now in my actual controller `Home.php` included `Frontend.php` at the top and extended home controller from `Frontend` controller.

That's all, now every time you create a new frontend controller extend it from `Frontend` controller.

Now in the same way I can create another controller for my backend controllers and extend all my backend controllers from it.

Enjoy..!!

Answer (score 3):

Put this code at the end of `APPPATH . 'config.php'` file:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    if (substr($class,0,3) !== 'CI_') {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . '.php')) {
            include $file;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant EXT - assumed 'EXT'

Filename: config/config.php

Line Number: 526

Backtrace:

File: /home/acephm3/public_html/phenomesoft.com/application/config/config.php
Line: 526
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/acephm3/public_html/phenomesoft.com/application/controllers/Home.php
Line: 3
Function: spl_autoload_call

File: /home/acephm3/public_html/phenomesoft.com/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Comment: Try now. I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
include_once('Frontend_Controller.php');
```

To:

```
include_once( APPPATH.'core/Frontend_Controller.php' );
```

In Home controller

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could try is

**Filename:** MY_Controller.php

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
   // Code Here
}

class Frontend_Controller extends MY_Controller {
    // Code here
}
```

With the front end controller class on the same file as MY_Controller.php

Home Controller

File name: Home.php

```
<?php

class Home extends Frontend_Controller {

}
```